# What data-structure is this (looks like an Array) and how can I access it? Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, parse-platform

I'm connecting to Parse.com using the parse-ruby-client gem.

I'm retrieving some photo data that seems like an array (if I .class it, is tells me array).

But I dont know how to access the data inside:

```
my_photos = [Photo:hoGXC2uRKf {"image"=>#<Parse::File:123 @parse_filename="name-1", @url="http://...">, "objectId"=>"hoGXC2uRKf", "user"=>#<Parse::Pointer:0x007f97152421e8 @class_name="_User", @parse_object_id="aFqn1XREtp">}, Photo:9GpFS26PsR {...etc]
```

So how can I get the **objectId** for the first photo for example?
(without using my_photos[0])

I want to get the data according to **objectId**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ruby, but that appears to be an array of [hash](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html)s.  What happens if you `.class` `my_photos[0]`?

Comment: @PyNewb it returns:  => Parse::Object

Comment: Well, there you have it--an array of [Parse::Object](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Object.html#constructor)s.  Are you able to access the object ID for a particular photo by going `my_photos[0]["objectId"]`?

Comment: Yeah! I transformed all of them into hashes and could manipulate the objects like you said! Thanks

Comment: Great!  I wrote it up as a quick answer.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this is an array of [Parse::Objects](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Object.html#constructor), which appear to be [Hash](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html)-like.  You can access an element of the array by subscripting with an index `[0]`, and a named element of the hash by subscripting with the key `["objectId"]`.